how to add spline in your next js project since I am have difficulty
this is the code
This is the screen it should the animation on
This is the animation I made in Spline
I tried it as the youtube instructed but got no luck and didnt found any solid lead on the internet till now
I need your guys assistance as it will help me complete the project if is my portfolio website let me know if you can assist in this project

Please, do not post your code as an image. Post it as actual code - edit your question, and add the code. Here's why.
